# Passing String Array In WCF Web Services

Tags: c#, wcf

My web service now looks like this:

```
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetAllAreaNotes", Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract, CorsEnabled]
        [Description("Request to get all area note")]
        AreaNote[] GetAllAreaNotes();

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetAreaNotesByIDs", Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract, CorsEnabled]
        [Description("Request to get area notes by IDs")]
        AreaNote[] GetAreaNotesByIDs();
```

The /GetAllAreaNotes is already working. /GetAreaNotesByIDs should be similar, but I'm not sure how to pass a string array in this web service. Here's my questions:

1. If this is still a Get request, it possible to pass string arrays as part of the URL?
2. Or, I should make it a POST request instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We can’t pass the string array as part of the URL. If you want to pass parameters through the URL, the parameter type can only be a string.**

***The solution is to use the POST method:***

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetAllAreaNotes", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string[] GetAllAreaNotes(string[] test);
```

We can enable the help document in WCF:

```
           <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ESEndPointBehavior">
                    <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
```

[image]

In the help document, we can see the request format and response format of the service.

[image]